# Вывод данных из файла txt в PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть такой код, как реализовать функцию (не сильно меняя код) которая будет сравнивать ID в списке user_id.txt и в зависимости от True или False (есть или нету этот ID в списке) будет отправлять соответствующий запрос...

Если пишет первый пользователь, он срабатывает как должен:

> П -> Подписка
>
> О -> Спасибо что подписался...
>
> П -> Подписка
>
> О -> Я не могу тебя подписаться...

Но когда пишет второй пользователь по данной схеме, то до момента "Я не могу..." он не доходит, хотя ID пользователя есть в списке... Я новичок в PHP, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

---

```
$file_join = fopen("user_id.txt", "r"); //Открываем файл //Поиск ранее вписанных ID
$buffer_join = fread($file_join, filesize("user_id.txt")); //Читаем файл
fclose($file);  //закрываем файл


if($user_msg == "Подписаться"){
    if($user_id == "$buffer_join"){
        $v->msgSend("Я не могу тебя подписаться, ты уже подписан на рассылку!", $user_id, $access_token);           
    } else {
        $v->msgSend("Спасибо что подписался на рассылку.
        Что бы отписаться от рассылки отправьте мне: «Отписка».", $user_id, $access_token);
        $file = fopen("user_id.txt", "r"); //Открываем файл //Поиск ранее вписанных ID
        $buffer = fread($file, filesize("user_id.txt")); //Читаем файл
        fclose($file);  //закрываем файл
    if (substr_count($buffer, "$user_id")>0){ //Ищем ID пользователя // Сходство найдено
    } else { //Сходство не найдено
        $fp = fopen("user_id.txt", "a"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи 
        $mytext = "$user_id;\n"; // Исходная строка
        $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); // Запись в файл
        fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
        }}}
```

---

Список ID в файле user_id.txt выглядит так.

```
29674938; 
14143596;
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя в buffer_join попадает строка в которой что-то типа 29674938;/n14143596; - соответственно это условие не будет отрабатывать user_id = buffer_join
Попробуйте перебирать каждую строку отдельно используя конструкцию:

```
$file_join = fopen("user_id.txt", 'r');
while (!feof($file_join )) {
    if($user_msg == "Подписаться"){
        if($user_id == "$file_join"){
          ... ваш код ...
      }
   }
}
fclose($file_join );
```

Comment: Не помогает, может делаю что-то не так... Но он мне вместо одного ответа отправил 100 менее чем за 5 сек.